# Source of URL Redirect

Tags: url, redirect, iis-7

I have a website that has a URL redirect going on and I'm trying to figure out where it is being done. I thought it was through the domain company (GoDaddy) but I removed any forwarding there and it still happens. Their support told be because the IP address redirects itself redirects (not just the domain name), it's not on there end. It uses IIS7 but there is nothing in the HTTP Redirect. It's an ASP.NET site with forms authentication.

Basically whenever I try to hit any page on the domain it redirects to a login URL the first time. Once the page is up it navigates fine but I need to be able to hit a sales page from a third party site without the login.

Anybody have thoughts on where else the redirect could be happening? Thanks

Comment: Not really enough info to be able to solve here, also it's not really a programming/development related question.

Comment: I guess it depends on where the redirect is happening whether it is a development issue or not. Looking for suggestions on where to look. Would my forms authentication toss me there even though the page I am landing on isn't locked down with a web.config denying access?